# TextView different ways to add drawable

Tags: android, textview, android-drawable

where is the difference between [`TextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)'s methods to set drawable? Documentation is quite vague.

```
1) setCompoundDrawables (Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, Drawable bottom)
2) setCompoundDrawablesRelative (Drawable start, Drawable top, Drawable end, Drawable bottom)
3) setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, Drawable bottom)
4) setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(Drawable start, Drawable top, Drawable end, Drawable bottom)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`setCompoundDrawables` requires you to call `setBounds(Rect)` on the `Drawable`(s) manually, whereas `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` will determine the bounds of the `Drawable` for you (kind of like setting an `ImageView` to `wrap_content`).

`setCompoundDrawablesRelative` is identical to `setCompoundDrawables`, except rather than using "left" and "right", it uses "start" and "end", which is useful if you want to support both left-to-right and right-to-left localizations ([see this blog post for more info](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html)). Same applies to `setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds` and `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds`.